# How to create some kind of context in a NodeJS application, I can access in all functions I call from there?

Tags: node.js

In Meteor (a NodeJS Framework), there is a function called `Meteor.userId()` that always returns the userId that belongs to the current session as long as I am in a function that was original called from a `Meteor Method`.

The `Meteor.userId()` function utilizes meteors `DDP?._CurrentInvocation?.get()?.connection`. So somehow this "Magic line" gets my current DDP connection. This also works when burried deep inside of callbacks.

So somehow meteor sets a context that it refers to. I also want to do this kind of trick for another API that doesn't utilize meteors DDP but is a plain HTTP Api.

What I want to do:

```
doActualStuff = function(param1, param2, param3) {
    // here, i am burried deep inside of calls to functions
    // but the function at the top of the stack trace was 
    // `answerRequest`. 
    // I want to access its `context` here but without 
    // passing it through all the function calls.
    // What I want is something like this:
    context = Framework.getRequestContext()
}

answerRequest = function(context) {
    //do some stuff
    someFancyFunctionWithCallback(someArray, function(arrayPosition) {
        aFuncCallingDoActualStuff(arrayPosition);
    })
}
```

I can wrap the call to `answerRequest` if this is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is called AsyncLocalStorage

https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#async_context_class_asynclocalstorage
and here an example how it can be used
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/async-local-storage

It works basically like thread local variables in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Meteor does it, but it doesn't look like magic. It looks like `Meteor` is a global object (`window.Meteor` in the browser or `global.Meteor` in Node.js) that has some functions that refer to some stateful object that exists in the context where they were defined.

Your example could be achieved by having `answerRequest` (or whatever function calls `answerRequest`, or whatever you want) call a `setRequestContext` function that sets the state that will be returned by `getRequestContext`. If you wanted, you could have an additional function, `clearRequestContext`, that cleans up after request is over. (Of course, if you have async code you'll need to take care that the latter isn't called until any code that needs that data has finished running.)

This is rudimentary, but it might look something like the below snippet. `window.Framework` does not need to be defined in the same file as the rest of the code; it just needs to be initialized before `answerRequest` is called.

```js
let _requestContext = null;

window.Framework = {
  setRequestContext(obj) {
    _requestContext = obj;
  },

  getRequestContext() {
    return _requestContext;
  },
  
  clearRequestContext() {
    _requestContext = null;
  },
};

const doActualStuff = function(param1, param2, param3) {
  const context = Framework.getRequestContext()
  console.log('Request context is', context);
}

const answerRequest = function(context) {
  Framework.setRequestContext(context);
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      doActualStuff();
    } finally {
      Framework.clearRequestContext();
    }
  }, 100);
}

answerRequest({ hello: 'context' });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: I think this will not work, as if I call the API twice and in between there are Database Calls, the context will be overwritten on the callback.